# ActiveMq, springBoot - immediately process every message sent on queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using ActiveMq with SpringBoot, to send every record from large csv file to another service. I am loading records to a map and then in a for each loop I send records to ActiveMq Queue.

My problem is that, ActiveMq wont let any consumer to take record from queue, until all records from my map are sent to ActiveMq.

Can I configurate ActiveMq to allow consuming message immediately after being put on queue (and not wating for some kind of commit transaction)?

Here's my ActiveMq Config:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

@Autowired
private JmsErrorHandler jmsErrorHandler;

@Autowired
private MessageConverter messageConverter;

@Autowired
private DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;

@Autowired
private DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory handlerMethodFactory;

@Autowired
private JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter;

@Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
private String brokerUrl;

@Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username, password, brokerUrl);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(true);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    return new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory,
                                                                  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler);
    configurer.configure(defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory, activeMQConnectionFactory);
    return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory handlerMethodFactory() {
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(createJacksonObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@NotNull
private ObjectMapper createJacksonObjectMapper() {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
            .json()
            .modules(new JavaTimeModule())
            .build();
}

@Override
public void configureJmsListeners(@NotNull JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(handlerMethodFactory);
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate createJmsTemplate(ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

}

I am sending messages with following code:

```
   public void sendRecordToLogbook(Record record) {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(logbookDestination, record);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by implementing my own connection, session and producer for each message instead of using JMSTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

The same Thing what you did using active MQ, I am doing the same thing using AWS SQS.
In SQS the queue message can be read at the same time when we write it, and once it read it will automatically delete from the queue.
So I suggest using AWS SQS to achieve your functionality.